Is "which is frustrating" correct in this sentence?

The reason I almost managed to hit 10 km yesterday was that I looked for chicken breast in three different outlets, which is frustrating.

Is "which is frustrating" correct ? It is a non restrictive clause.
Why I feel weird is because it doesn't have subject. Or
"The reason I almost managed to hit 10 km yesterday was that I looked for chicken breast in three outlets" is the subject itself and " which is frustrating " is a predicate.

It's an odd sentence. Presumably the speaker means that they had to visit three different shops before they were able to buy chicken breast (or maybe they didn't find any at all?). It would be more logical to say "...which was frustrating", since the experience happened yesterday.

@KateBunting The reason why I almost managed to hit 10 km yesterday was because I looked for chicken breast in 3 different outlets that turned out to not have chicken breast, which was frustrating.  How about this ?

Is this a sentence you are writing for yourself? (In which case it's proofreading and therefore off-topic.) Your new version is unnecessarily repetitive.

It's a fairly common colloquial way of putting it.  You might even say "Which is frustrating" as a separate sentence. See this question on English Language and Usage

@KateBunting The issue with "proofreading" questions is simply that they don't specify what the problem is. I feel like this question does a good job of communicating its concern. "Proofreading" certainly doesn't mean that no one can ask about text they create themselves; that would be pretty limiting!

OK, I've retracted my close vote. @Jed'sClass - There is no need to repeat 'chicken breast'. I had to look in three different outlets before I could find any chicken breast  (Having to look in three places implies that you didn't find any in the first two.)

I'd say "which was frustrating" since it happened in the past, but otherwise it seems OK.

There's an understood predicate, which requires only "understanding" a verb to be in another tense. Let's take an even simpler sentence:

I just ran 10 km, which is tiring.

What's the predicate of "which is tiring"? "Running 10 km" is. Or "to run," if you want. We used the tense of "run" that matched our main clause, but the second clause can still refer to the verb in the abstract.
So the reasonable predicate in your chicken-finding sentence is perhaps "looking for chicken breast in three different outlets," or even a bit more of understood omitted words, like "having to look for [etc.]."

In your it doesn't have subject, I believe you mean
the relative pronoun which doesn't have an antecedent.
The relative pronoun
which in the non-restrictive relative
clause
which is frustrating does have an antecedent.
It is the entire preceding clause that I looked for chicken breast in three different outlets.
What you’ve stated to be a possible antecedent is less likely:

The reason ... three different outlets.

The frustration is more
likely the travel to three outlets rather than the explanation for The reason.
As for the use of is or was, we should
use was if the frustration has subsided.  If it is still there, we can use either one.
